# Unable to migrate from Legacy Multisig to Safe due to maxFeePerGas error

Tags: gnosis-safe, gnosis

I am a user of Legacy Multisig who is trying to migrate assets to Gnosis-Safe from an older Multisig with signatories all using Light Wallet

It has always worked flawlessly. I've not looked at it since earlier this year. But now, when I try and execute a transaction I get the following error:
`max fee per gas less than block base fee: address 0x16a67c3e4289Ba8D4481C4d15ec37C8788d57D81, maxFeePerGas: 18000000000 baseFee: 56103629628 (supplied gas 13497304)`

Is this a known issue?

Comment: Seems to be related to EIP-1559, the old interface does not support this and therefore probably sets an invalid gasprice

Comment: Yes makes sense, and this also affects the legacy web interface as well. The  question is if/when Gnosis will add a new release version onto their Github page.

Comment: Gnosis is not maintaining the old MultiSig repo anymore. The repository is archived and there is no more work being done on it.

Comment: Hi guys I am having the same problem here. What should I do in this case? Any solution please?

Comment: You can ask a developer friend to write a script to interact with the multisig.

Comment: What web interface are you using?

Comment: @user89643 I'd interact directly with the smart contract using a different front-end, you can potentially do it through Etherscan, or through remix if you know how to use it.

What's the contract's address?